# MAC virtual machine issue with Android device

Tags: android, macos, usb, virtualbox

I've been trying to deploy Android app on MAC virtual machine but it does not recognise Android device via USB port or wifi (using Android ADB wifi plugin). Below are what I've been trying to do:

- Shutdown guest OS
- Plug in the device and let host OS grab it
- Enable USB controller from virtualbox menu Machine-->settings-->usb enable usb controller and enable USB 1.1 (the other options are not valid).
- Turn on USB Debugging option
- Start guest OS

However, the device has always been in 'offline' state. Any suggestion please?

Comment: did you switch device to developer mode?

Comment: Yes, that's done too

Comment: I've got it solved after installing extension pack for the version of VirtualBox and use USB 3.0 instead of USB 1.1.